# Apache shows blank white page after 2 to 10 hours

Tags: networking, server, apache2, security

I am using ubuntu 12.04, it has to network cards, A = internal 10.0.0.0 and B public Ip , I have only apache2 installed, after 2 to 10 hours the website shows as a blank white page on the public network but continues to appear normally on the private 10.0.0.0 network, if I login or sometimes restart apache or the server the site comes back on the public network, but after 2 to 10 hours will become a blank white page and in chrome sometimes err_empty_response. the apache logs show no problems, the external firewall is setup and working properly, there is no port forwarding and the gateway on the server is correct. this is driving me crazy now, I have reinattled multiple times, removing php on the next install, I have 3 seperate servers all doing the same thing, I have a 4th email server which is fine, no problems, and 2 nameservers with no problems, all ubuntu 12.04, this problem appeared about 3 months ago after the servers were working fine for 6 months, it just started, i had posted a similar post and closed it assuming it wasnt an ubuntu problem bu this has to be. not sure if it could be a security issue. I have performed the following security on all 3.

**Secure shared memory**
vi /etc/fstab
tmpfs     /dev/shm     tmpfs     defaults,noexec,nosuid     0     0

**SSH Hardening** 
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin no

**Protect su by limiting access only to admin group.**
sudo groupadd admin
sudo usermod -a -G admin my-username
sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add root admin 4750 /bin/su

**Harden network with sysctl settings**

## IP Spoofing protection

net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

## Ignore ICMP broadcast requests

net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1

## Disable source packet routing

net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

## Ignore send redirects

net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0

## Block SYN attacks

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 5

## Log Martians

net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1

## Ignore ICMP redirects

net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0 
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0

**Prevent IP Spoofing**
vi /etc/host.conf
order bind,hosts
nospoof on

Then in apache I performed the following

**installed it**

apt-get install apache2

**Disable Directory Listings**
/etc/apache2/conf.d/security
ServerToken Prod
ServerSignature Off

**Disabling unnecessary modules**
a2dismod status
a2dismod autoindex
rm -f /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/autoindex.load
rm -f /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/autoindex.conf
rm -f /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav.load
rm -f /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_fs.conf
rm -f /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_fs.load
rm -f /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_lock.load

Also I have webmin installed on port 10000.

if I login to webmin or ssh into the server using putty the site appers again sometimes on the public network, keep in mind the site appears normally the entire time on the private network and also if I'm on the same subnet at the public network. it only across the net that this problem occurs, I have verizon fios with 10 public ip's.

this is my configuration, not sure if anything is creating an issue. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked cabling and / or the network adapter on the public IP? It sounds like a defective HW or power saving mode gets turned on due to lack of traffic. Try to replug the cable when this happens or send a magic packet. Try with a different switch. Does the switch turn off the port? Make sure it is not the network adapter or the connection that is causing your problems.

Comment: I like your answers, I've already replaced the switch, the cables have bben replaced and the card should be fine because if i'm on the same subnet i can see the site, it's when i'm outside the gateway that the problems begin. this problem occurs all 3 seperate servers, it started at the same time.

Comment: Ok I have an update, I have reinstalled several times, the current install was stripped down to eliminate possible conflicts, I have only installed ubuntu 12.04 with apache2, the problem remains the same, after a day or 2 the site is unavailable outside my subnet, however if i'm on the same subnet the site comes righ up, it's as if the gateway setting disappears, now for the strange part, if I ssh in and login, or I open webmin and login the site comes back outside my subnet, I have checkedthe logs and nothing, I have checked my external firewall and nothing. there is no router, just verizon

Comment: The only possible conclusion I can draw is that for some unexplained reason or cause the gateway disappears or stops after a day or 2, I even setup a cron job that restarts apache2 every 6 hours, this only works for a day or 2 then the same problem occurs, I have even tried using the ip for the website and it's the same result, it's asif the gateway shuts off and turns back on when I login via ssh or webmin, note: simply ssh to the ip or opening the webmin login page wont fix it, it's only after I login that the site turns back on outside my subnet. this is driving me crazy. please help

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to your question. I'd suspect your uplink service provider, but that is only a guess. It is not clear to me though, what do you mean by „on the same subnet”. Is that a LAN connection, or a WAN connection through a different gateway?

Comment: Sorry I mean on my local network before it goes through the gateway and across verizon. the confusing part is that if I login via ssh or webmin the site comes back up outside my gateway, would that eliminate my isp?

Comment: This actually might mean that your ISP closes the inbound connection for HTTP. If I recall correctly Webmin uses a different port, so does SSH. It might worth a try to bring this up with your ISP, if they actually close the inbound port after being ~ 48 hours idle. Have you tried to set up a „pinger” script (e.g. download a page with `wget` every few hours) just to keep the connection alive?

Comment: That makes sense, no I didnt know you could do that with wget, thanks I will try it and also talk to isp, thanks for your help, let you know

Comment: just out of curiosity could my security settings be timing out or causing the issue?

Comment: Ok I contacted my isp, they checked the logs of their router and said they are no problems on their end, they said that the problem is on my 3 servers, I am at a loss as to what it could be, not sure what would cause this issue.

Comment: I can offer a few more tips how to test, but do not know the specific reason. 1) I'd check if the public IP did not change during the timeouts, if that's possible. 2) I'd try to install the required minimal software without the „hardening” settings and see if that works. 3) I'd try to set up that pinger script that downloads a page from the internet every few hours, and log the output. That could shed light on connectivity issues, timeout issues or similar.

Comment: ok thanks I will try that, just to give you an update, when the problem occurs on the outside, the machines are not even accessible by ip either, however they are on the local subnet

Comment: Just wanted to give you an update, I relaxed the security settings and still had that issue, then I used a wget spider cron job and the problem went away, I contacted my ips and they insist the problem is on my end.

Comment: This is somewhat good news, so you'll need to check your broadband router if it keeps an always-on connection or uses an on-demand one. The latter ceases to work after inactivity, therefore the wget job keeps it alive.